# Dual booting Ubuntu on a separate drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I know similar questions have been asked however why am I asking is because I wanted to know say i install Ubuntu on my D Drive instead of my C Drive (which has my windows on it). My D Drive is a 1 TB drive and I have files installed on it. If i put Ubuntu on it will i still be able to use the space that has not been partitioned off and can i still use it to say download things on my windows os? I ask this because i recently installed and deleted Ubuntu because after installation I noticed that I couldn't access my D Drive from Windows anymore and naturally all my files on it were gone. Basically I am asking if there is any way around this or was it just because i installed Ubuntu wrong.....?

Comment: Only use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition to make unallocated space. Then reboot immediately and run chkdsk on the NTFS partition. Then you can install Ubuntu into the unallocated space or use gparted to manually create partitions in advance. Only use Something Else install option to choose or create / (root) & swap. If swap created in advance it will find it automatically. Is system UEFI or BIOS. Will make some difference on where boot loader should be and partitioning of second drive.

Comment: My system is a UEFI if possible can you please describe the steps necessary? I dont want to run into the issue of having to reformat my entire drive again

Comment: the Manual Partitioning question does not answer my question on how to keep the actual drive i use for windows working. As in after i install Ubuntu on a drive i still want to be able to access the leftover space on that drive as say storage, i want to be able to use that storage on windows. I dont get the point of partioning say 60 gb for Ubuntu and then have Ubuntu take over my entire drive.

Comment: The partition sizes given in the answers to that questions are just examples. You can adjust them however you want as long as the partition(s) for Ubuntu are large enough for their purpose (≥ 5 GB for the system itself and ~4 GB for swap if you want that).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I was moving to ubuntu. To dual boot ubuntu with windows you need to have seperate HDDs to my knowledge.

Do you really want to move to ubuntu then try it on a virtual box first.

Comment: I just want to have the option of having both ubuntu and windows since i want to get some experience in linux. But like i said i want to put it on my 2nd drive but at the same time still be able to use that second drive on my windows os

Comment: Why don't you try ubuntu on a virtual box?

Comment: I wouldnt mind but luckily i just recently got ubuntu working...at least to some extent

Comment: I think now it allows dual booting. When I reinstall ubuntu on a windows laptop, It provided that option. But I did not try.